# Eclipse shortcuts for Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I just switched from Eclipse to android studio. Just want to know if there is a way to import my shortcuts from eclipse to android studio.

I know there is an option in android studio to use eclipse default shortcuts:

```
File--> Settings --> Keymap --> Keymaps --> choose eclipse .
```

(However by doing this you'll not have all eclipse shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or ...)

But I did not find any way to import all of my custom shortcuts from Eclipse to Android Studio.
Any help Would be appreciated.

Comment: there is button of pen below the keymaps there you can add the shortcuts

Comment: As of now the only way is via the menu option + you have to change every keymap you had on your own.

Comment: @Android yes of course but i want to import all of my shortcuts at one time, not adding them one by one ;)

Comment: @Radix: I'm hoping to find a new way. BTW thanks man ;)

Comment: @Milad apart from tht there is no other option...atleast not in my knowledge.. wait for other ans. :)

Comment: @Android yea I wait to :D

Answer (score 1):

Do following changes in your android studio go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java

1) Change Insert imports on paste value to "All"

2) Mark Add unambigious imports on the fly option as checked

Let me know if you still facing any issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, by doing that Auto Import problem solved but I still not able to import all of my custom shortcuts into android studio ;)

Comment: For that you need to perform changes in keymap> particular keyboard shortcut

Comment: you mean add my shortcuts one by one ?

Comment: no perform changes in exits shortcuts like to reformat code the shortcut is ctrl+shift+f you can change it as per your requirement

Comment: OK, I know that but it takes time. I was searching for a way to import all of my shortcuts at one time. not changing them one by one

Comment: I am searching for Export-Import procedure to export these settings form eclipse and import them to Android Studio.

Comment: still now i didn't get this option. if you will get also let me know